# Is IP address from GoogleAppEngine URLFetch in same project static?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is IP address from GoogleAppEngine URLFetch in same project static?

I read [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip)

I want to know IP address of subnetmask 24-30 is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You may find that your outbound requests come from the same IP address for a period of time, but you may also find different instances are allocated to different addresses.

As far as I can tell, Google doesn't allocate IP ranges to specific services (App Engine, Compute Engine, URLFetch, etc), so you should probably assume that your URLFetch requests could come from any of the blocks published in these DNS records:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
```

You will see that's a *big* address space, so it's best to try to avoid any security measures that rely on a static address.